# Is it legal to stub the #class method of a Mock object when using RSpec in a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, rspec, mocking, stub

I would like to stub the #class method of a mock object:

```
describe Letter do
  before(:each) do
    @john = mock("John")
    @john.stub!(:id).and_return(5)
    @john.stub!(:class).and_return(Person)  # is this ok?
    @john.stub!(:name).and_return("John F.")
    Person.stub!(:find).and_return(@john)
  end
  it.should "have a valid #to field" do
    letter = Letter.create!(:to=>@john, :content => "Hello John")
    letter.to_type.should == @john.class.name
    letter.to_id.should == @john.id
  end
  [...]
end
```

On line 5 of this program, I stub the #class method, in order to allow things like @john.class.name.  Is this the right way to go?  Will there be any bad side effect?

*Edit:*

The Letter class looks like this:

```
class Letter < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :to, :polymorphic => true
    [...]
end
```

I wonder whether ActiveRecord gets the :to field's class name with `to.class.name` or by some other means.  Maybe this is what the class_name method is ActiveRecord::Base is for?

Comment: I have no knowledge of a legislation against it... I guess it's `legal` ;) :)

Comment: Phew... I was afraid I'd go to jail!  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be using `mock_model` for this particular case.
Your `before(:each)` would look like that:

```
before(:each) do
  @john = mock_model(Person, :name => "John F.")
  Person.stub!(:find).and_return(@john)
end
```

Then for your other question, you should not really care about how Rails works to test your behaviour. I don't think it's a good idea to test to_type and to_id fields yourself. This is Rails behaviour and as such should be tested in Rails, not in your project.

I have been using [Remarkable](http://remarkable.rubyforge.org/) for a while and it makes this really easy to specify:

```
describe Letter
  should_belong_to :to, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Comment: @MiniQuark glad it was useful, even after all this time :)